# Timeout when granting permissions

Tags: 2013, permissions

When creating an item, I delete the default permissions and grant permissions to about 40 groups and it gives me a timeout error.

Can I change the timeout?
Is there a way to grant different permissions to 40 groups in a batch mode?

This is a legacy code and I have seen that for every permission granted it opens a new RunWithElevatedPrivileges - using new site()..., so it opens a context 40 times and I think that it should be done once, what do you think?

Comment: If you can still manipulate the code or rewrite your own, then running in `RunWIthElevatedPrivileges` shouldn't be a problem as long as you do everything inside that. Then again, maybe you could give some better explanation about your possibilities

Comment: Hi Taurib, I can modify the code and my idea is to take everything inside RunWitheElevated instead of calling 40 times to a function that uses Runwithelevated

Comment: I'd suggest you to collect all those groups to an array (List) and run them at once if you can. And use `RunWIthElevatedPrivileges` when going through that loop. I've had some problems, when using `RunWIthElevatedPrivileges` through multiple methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change time Out from web.config file of you web

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0"    executionTimeout="999999" maxUrlLength="1024" />
<system.web>
```

Or you can used SPLongOperation if you created solution in VS

```
using (SPLongOperation longOperation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))
{
     //Show Text for the Top Line on the screen.
     longOperation.LeadingHTML = "Working on it....";
     //Show text for the Bottom line on the screen.
     longOperation.TrailingHTML = "Please wait it will take few minuts";

     //Write you code here

     longOperation.End("~/home.aspx");
 }
```